# Numpy segfault on large SVD as user but not as root

Tags: python, linux, numpy

I'm trying compute the SVD of a largeish dense matrix (10k X 10k) using numpy's SVD. I'm using linux mint, and have built numpy against the multi-threaded version of ATLAS.

When I attempt to do this using my user account, the code immediately exits with a SegFault. I happened to try again using a shell with root privileges and the operation completed successfully.

It doesn't seem to depend on the matrix. I tried

```
A = eye(10000)
[U,S,V] = svd(A)
```

and it exhibited the same behavior.

I'm guessing that this is really a linux question rather than a numpy one but I was wondering if anyone has experienced something similar or had an idea on the cause or possible solutions. I would prefer not to have to run my code as root for obvious reasons.

Comment: I would check if you are using the same python and libraries with the two accounts. Maybe the PATH, PYTHOPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH env vars are different and you are using a different version with the root account.

Comment: Yes thank you very much.  The root is using a numpy built without ATLAS.  I'm thinking that the problem is actually in that library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the comment is the answer, hence re-posting it as such:

I would check if you are using the same python and libraries with the two accounts. Maybe the PATH, PYTHONPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH env vars are different and you are using a different version with the root account.